# -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch breaks on iPad when toggeling visibility of div on iPad

Tags: css, ipad, webkit, overflow

I have a a tabbed section, where each tab section is scrollable.
When ever i use `display:none`, `visibility:hidden` or changing the `z-index`, the webkit scroll does not work any more.

The only way I can keep the scroll but hide a tab sections, is to set the top position to -786px, so it goes above ipads page fold.

Any idea whats going on here?

Tested on iPad 2 iOs5 in a UIWebView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same issue here. Used negative y offset is the only workaround I found.